# Cannot initialize Masonry with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

According to the [official documentation](http://masonry.desandro.com/) there are different ways to initialize the masonry container. The HTML initialization works fine, but when I try to move the parameters from the data-masonry attribute to JQuery, things break.

Here is the HTML initialization with the JSON params.

```
<div id="container" class="masonry js-masonry"  data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer", "itemSelector": ".item", "isFitWidth": true }'>
```

And then this is what it currently looks like when I move these to my js/JQuery-file:

```
var $container = $('#container');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  itemSelector: '.item',
  isFitWidth: true
});
```

Using the latter version, the grid-sizer element goes visible, which should not show up, of course.

I see no specification in the official documentation about when I need to call the initialization code in JQuery. Is it $(document).ready where I can call this?

JSFIDDLE with broken layout: http://jsfiddle.net/1f1kwfbd/10/

Comment: Yes you call it in the $(document).ready function after the page has loaded.

Comment: @Jackson Unfortunatelly, I get a broken masonry grid. I have updated my question and added a jsfiddle.

Comment: You need to load masonry as an external resource in your jsfiddle! Use a [CDN](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js)  It won't work without loading it! Your gird sizer should not have content inside it: `<div class="grid-sizer"></div>` and it needs to have it's own css rule, not linked to your .item css, like this:  `.grid-sizer { width: 33.33333%; }`. Fix that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see no specification in the official documentation about when I need
>   to call the initialization code in JQuery. Is it $(document).ready
>   where I can call this?

So you can call this whenever you want.

The quickest way would indeed be on document.ready - this would fire it as soon as the page loads e.g

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#container');
    // initialize
    $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      itemSelector: '.item',
      isFitWidth: true
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could encapsulate your masonry code within a function and choose to call this at a later time. e.g

```
// Declare your function
function initMasonry() {
    var $container = $('#container');
    // initialize
    $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      itemSelector: '.item',
      isFitWidth: true
    });
}
```

To call the function just call it like so:

```
initMasonry();
```

**Update**

After reading the docs for masonry, you need to create a new masonry object as opposed to init the masonry object on your jQuery selector.

Example code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isFitWidth: true
    });

});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjbq4gj6/

Docs for reference: http://masonry.desandro.com/#javascript

Comment: Exactly the same code I am working with at the moment, but the .grid-sizer div is visible and on resizing the window things overlap. See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1f1kwfbd/1/

Comment: I didn't make up this element, DeSandro's documentation uses it too, e.g. this codepen:  http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JFpeg The CSS doesn't hide it.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster I can't see anything in your fiddle that sets the grid-sizer element to not display. Also what is the purpose of this element?

Comment: @DrunkenMaster So your masonry won't fire on your fiddle because you haven't referenced the library. You need to add an external resource to your fiddle. I've added it via the external resources menu on the left hand side and now the masonry is executing. But it appears it hasn't solved your problem yet. http://jsfiddle.net/1f1kwfbd/9/

Comment: Oh, that's true, nevertheless, the .grid-sizer element still shows up, unless I use HTML initialization. Here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1f1kwfbd/10/

Comment: @DrunkenMaster Fixed your problem - it relates to the way you call the masonry method. See my updated answer above.

Comment: Hmm, not fixed since your grid-sizer still shows. See my comment above about the css for the grid-sizer and see an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjbq4gj6/) with the grid-sizer issue fixed.

Comment: @Macsupport I just noticed that too - well spotted. I think that should fix all issues. Upvoted :)

Comment: @Macsupport Thanks all, it turned out that I have other issues and Masonry might not be the best option for my project.