# Can't get masonry to work with HTML initialization

Tags: html, css, masonry

Images appear at full size in a single column. Masonry doesn't appear to be doing anything at all. I'll post some of my code. Please note, I may be doing something wrong that's very elementary as its been a few years since I've worked with HTML/CSS

For a more complete understanding my my situation, here are the exact files I'm working with: 
https://github.com/bryanwillis7/artistWebsite
index.html is the main file. Css is in css/custom.css.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth":200 }'>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><img src="art/yugioh.jpg" class="art"></img></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><img src="art/splashwoman.png" class="art"></img></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><img src="art/shrinking_shroom.png" class="art"></img></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><img src="art/sam_sip.png" class="art"></img></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><img src="art/melia.png" class="art"></img></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.grid-item {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

div.grid-item--width2 {
  width: 400px;
}

div.grid-item--width3 {
  width: 600px;
}

div img.art {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, have you checked this out?

[Cannot initialize Masonry with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650030/cannot-initialize-masonry-with-jquery)

From my understanding you must use JavaScript or jquery to initialize masonry

Comment: I forgot to mention that your img tags have a closing tag when they shouldn't

Comment: I really sorry! You don't need jquery to initialize, I added a few css option which you can look at the above jsfiddle link. I changed the images to placeholders since I don't have your pictures... But it should work fine with your images, I also added a gutter-width option so that you could see the space the in between the pictures, you don't have to have that at all. You can see it is working if you resize the window

Comment: https://github.com/bryanwillis7/artistWebsite

Here's a github link with the exact project files I'm working with. I tried my best to apply what you've written to my code, but it still refuses to work. The CSS is in CSS/custom.css the index.html is the main file, and the images are in the art folder. If you could take a look I'd deeply appreciate it. Maybe you'll find something I'm missing.

Comment: Well damn, I've never worked with Sass files before, but when you add the css styling to the starter-template.css file, it works, somewhat. Somewhere along the line the Sass file isn't being added to the starter-template css, if that's how it should work?

Comment: It works fine... I had a few missing semi colons... I'll look into the Sass in a bit though to try and help out more, I'll get back to you as soon as I can!

Comment: The Sass literally isn't doing anything. Sass gets rendered to CSS, specifically, the file I mentioned css/custom.css is the stylesheet that the website is using. So ignore the sass file. The only reason it exist is to make CSS more pleasing to look at while I'm coding.

Comment: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/1063

I'm not the only one with this issue. Apparently Masonry not working with Bootstrap4 is a known issue.